# Hi I am trying to devolp a flutter application with firebase as back end. I am facing issue while connecting firebase Crashlytics with my app

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, crashlytics

I am new to flutter and firebase. I am trying develop an app with firebase as back end. To track the issues I thought of enabling the Crashlytics. I have enabled the crashlytics in the firebase console. i am getting the following message as Add SDK to your application

[image: After enabling Crashlytics]

Added firebase_crashlytics to my application

[image: firebase_crashlytics]

Followed the instructions provided in the firebase_crashlytics

Android/build.gradle

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.0'
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
    url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }
}
```

}
Andriod/App/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
```

}

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And updated my main file to initialize the firebase_crashlytics
[image]

I have manually thrown a null exception in the application. Which should be captured and shown on the crashlytic dashboard. Bit i am still getting add sdk loading icon in crashlytic dashboard. Please let me know what the issue. i have been working on this for past week.

I am able to save and read data with out any issue. I am working on my android app

Attached flutter doctor output

[image]

Comment: Your app may be stuck in a build state in the Firebase backend. If you message me your Project ID and bundle ID I can take look. Otherwise feel free to write in to Firebase Support and they can check.

As a troubleshooting step, you could also redownload your google services file, clean your project, and then try to build and run it again